# Flatten Array of Arrays That Contains Objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6, lodash

I have an issue with flattening array.

Given that the structure is following

```
{
  "name": "Somename",
  "property": [
    [
      {
        "prop": "someprop",
        "other": "someother"
      },
      {
        "prop": "someprop",
        "other": "someother"
      }
    ],
    [
      {
        "prop": "someprop",
        "other": "someother"
      },
      {
        "prop": "someprop",
        "other": "someother"
      },
      {
        "prop": "someprop",
        "other": "someother"
      },
      {
        "prop": "someprop",
        "other": "someother"
      }
    ],
    [
      {
        "prop": "someprop",
        "other": "someother"
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

Or maybe better illustrated with this pic[image]

How can I flatten matches into single array of objects or actually have flat structure where all nested items are in single array or object ?

I have managed to get so far by wrangling data but seem stuck at this I can use pretty much any library or tool and latest JS features.

I have tried mapping over values , reducing it using lodash deepMerge but cant seem to accomplish what I want.

Input:

```
const data = [
       {
        "sport": "Handball",
        "matches": [
            [
                {
                    "home": "Izmir BSB SK (Youth) (Wom)",
                    "away": "Bursa Osmangazi (Youth) (Wom)",
                    "ID": "3092996854"
                }
            ],
            [
                {
                    "home": "Al Muheet U21",
                    "away": "Al Mohmel U21",
                    "ID": "3092999932"
                }
            ]
        ]
    },
    {
        "sport": "Volleyball",
        "matches": [
            [
                {
                    "home": "Ji-Hee Choi/Michika Ozeki",
                    "away": "Panji Ahmad Maulana",
                    "ID": "3093062401"
                },
                {
                    "home": "Ryazan (Wom)",
                    "away": "Angara Irkutsk (Wom)",
                    "ID": "3093062393"
                }
            ],
            [
                {
                    "home": "CF Carthage (Wom)",
                    "away": "Winner - Broughton Excels",
                    "ID": "3093721823"
                }
            ],
            [
                {
                    "home": "Ankara Yildirim Beyazit Universitesi (Wom)",
                    "away": "Saglik Bilimleri Universitesi (Wom)",
                    "ID": "3093058567"
                }
            ]
        ]
    }
    ]
```

Expected output of each matches prop:

```
    {
      "sport": "Handball",
      "matches": [
        {home: '...', other: '...', id: '...'},
        {home: '...', other: '...', id: '...'},
        {home: '...', other: '...', id: '...'},
        {home: '...', other: '...', id: '...'},
      ]
    }
```

Comment: What is your expected output? `[{.?.},{.?.}]`

Comment: {
  "name": "Somename",
  "property": [
    {prop: 'someProp', other: 'otherProp'},
    {prop: 'someProp', other: 'otherProp'},
    {prop: 'someProp', other: 'otherProp'},
    {prop: 'someProp', other: 'otherProp'}
  ]
}

Comment: if you want to get help, show us expected output

Comment: add it to your question

Comment: `Or maybe better illustrated with this pic` - nope. We hate pics ;/

Comment: @georg There was a pic? I can't see them,.. :/ - I guess that's why this might apply, even if it is not code per-se [**Why not to upload Images of Code when asking a Question**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) - Also, who knows if that image-link is even there in 2 Month, making the question useless for future users if it is gone and the expected output isn't in the question.

Comment: I know i do but It would be hard explaining what I have and what I want to accomplish.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Merge/flatten an array of arrays in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10865025/merge-flatten-an-array-of-arrays-in-javascript)

Comment: It is similar but I have array of arrays that contains objects which are nested.

Comment: What do you mean with *I have array of arrays that contains objects which are nested*?  Can you post an example?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the function `reduce` and to check for array objects the function `Array.isArray`.

```js
var data = {  "name": "Somename",  "property": [    [      {        "prop": "someprop",        "other": "someother"      },      {        "prop": "someprop",        "other": "someother"      }    ],    [      {        "prop": "someprop",        "other": "someother"      },      {        "prop": "someprop",        "other": "someother"      },      {        "prop": "someprop",        "other": "someother"      },      {        "prop": "someprop",        "other": "someother"      }    ],    [      {        "prop": "someprop",        "other": "someother"      }    ]  ]};

data.property = data.property.reduce((mapped, p) => 
                [...mapped, ...(Array.isArray(p) ? p : [p])], []);
//                                    ^
//                                    |
//                                    +- This is to check for situations where 
//                                       a particular object is not an array.

console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks it has actually given me a hint that I was oblivious to.

Answer (score 0):

Use the spread operator and `array.concat`. `array.concat` has this unique condition where if the argument is an array, it adds the *contents* of that array to the result array instead of the array itself. The spread operator spreads the array's contents as args of the function, one after the other.

```
const flatProperties = [].concat(...data.property)
```

```js
const data = {
  "name": "Somename",
  "property": [
    [
      {
        "prop": "someprop",
        "other": "someother"
      },
      {
        "prop": "someprop",
        "other": "someother"
      }
    ],
    [
      {
        "prop": "someprop",
        "other": "someother"
      },
      {
        "prop": "someprop",
        "other": "someother"
      },
      {
        "prop": "someprop",
        "other": "someother"
      },
      {
        "prop": "someprop",
        "other": "someother"
      }
    ],
    [
      {
        "prop": "someprop",
        "other": "someother"
      }
    ]
  ]
}

const flatProperties = [].concat(...data.property)

console.log(flatProperties)
```

Comment: Yes but i have array of objects that have property which in turn has array of arrays. I did try it.

Comment: This `[].concat` is a bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.reduce` on your array

```
data.property = data.property.reduce(
  (acc, el) => acc.concat(el) , []
)
```

```js
var data = {
  "name": "Somename",
  "property": [
    [
      {
        "prop": "someprop",
        "other": "someother"
      },
      {
        "prop": "someprop",
        "other": "someother"
      }
    ],
    [
      {
        "prop": "someprop",
        "other": "someother"
      },
      {
        "prop": "someprop",
        "other": "someother"
      },
      {
        "prop": "someprop",
        "other": "someother"
      },
      {
        "prop": "someprop",
        "other": "someother"
      }
    ],
    [
      {
        "prop": "someprop",
        "other": "someother"
      }
    ]
  ]
};

data.property = data.property.reduce(
  (acc, el) => acc.concat(el) , []
)

console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `concat` and `apply` methods. This answer is similar to the answer by **Joseph** but without ES6 array spread operator

```js
var originalArray = {
  "name": "Somename",
  "property": [
    [
      {
        "prop": "someprop",
        "other": "someother"
      },
      {
        "prop": "someprop",
        "other": "someother"
      }
    ],
    [
      {
        "prop": "someprop",
        "other": "someother"
      },
      {
        "prop": "someprop",
        "other": "someother"
      },
      {
        "prop": "someprop",
        "other": "someother"
      },
      {
        "prop": "someprop",
        "other": "someother"
      }
    ],
    [
      {
        "prop": "someprop",
        "other": "someother"
      }
    ]
  ]
};

var flattened = [].concat.apply([],originalArray["property"]);
console.log(flattened)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using lodash, this works too.

```js
var data = {
  "name": "Somename",
  "property": [
    [
      {
        "prop": "someprop",
        "other": "someother"
      },
      {
        "prop": "someprop",
        "other": "someother"
      }
    ],
    [
      {
        "prop": "someprop",
        "other": "someother"
      },
      {
        "prop": "someprop",
        "other": "someother"
      },
      {
        "prop": "someprop",
        "other": "someother"
      },
      {
        "prop": "someprop",
        "other": "someother"
      }
    ],
    [
      {
        "prop": "someprop",
        "other": "someother"
      }
    ]
  ]
}

data.property = _.flattenDeep(data.property)

console.log(data);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.5/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I have to map over the original array and manipulate property that has nested array of objects I have tried lodash as well.

Answer (score 0):

you can use recursive function to traverse the array

```
const props = {
  "name": "Somename",
  "property": [
    [
      {
        "prop": "someprop",
        "other": "someother"
      },
      {
        "prop": "someprop",
        "other": "someother"
      }
    ],
    [
      {
        "prop": "someprop",
        "other": "someother"
      },
      {
        "prop": "someprop",
        "other": "someother"
      },
      {
        "prop": "someprop",
        "other": "someother"
      },
      {
        "prop": "someprop",
        "other": "someother"
      }
    ],
    [
      {
        "prop": "someprop",
        "other": "someother"
      }
    ]
  ]
};


function smoosh(populate) {
    return function _smoosh(arr) {
        if ( Array.isArray(arr) ) {
            for ( let value of arr ) {
                _smoosh(value);
            }
        }
        if ( typeof(arr) === "object" && ! Array.isArray(arr) ) {
            populate.push(arr);
        }
    };
}

const flatten = [];

smoosh(flatten)(props.property);

Object.assign(props,{
    property: flatten
});
console.log(props);
```